# Postgres add column and update

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 4 tables I want to add a column called Receptor_Name with there respective types for each layer

1. childcare's 2. schools 3. nursing homes 4. hospitals

I know i can manually add the column and set it for each table like this

```
alter table childcare add column Receptor_Name text;
update childcare set receptor_name = 'Childcares';
```

continuing for other layers...

I was wondering it there is a way to loop through them add the column field to each table and update it based on the table name

Comment: Sure using dynamic sql you can create a cursor or a loop to do something like this. but if you are just adding 1 column to 4 tables and 4 update statements it wont be worth your while.  Also setting the entire receptor_name = to the table name doesn't seem worth your while either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that using dynamic SQL, `EXECUTE` clause in PL/pgSQL is one way:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    tables text[] := ARRAY['childcare', 'schools', 'nursing homes', 'hospitals'];
    tbl_name text;
BEGIN
    FOREACH tbl_name IN ARRAY tables LOOP
        EXECUTE
            format('ALTER TABLE %I ADD receptor_name text;', tbl_name);
        EXECUTE
            format('UPDATE %I SET receptor_name = $1;', tbl_name)
            USING initcap(tbl_name);
    END LOOP;
END;
$$;
```